# Unable to start react-native application on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have just started learning react-native on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine with 4GB RAM i3(5th gen) processor. When I try to run `react-native start` it shows error `ENOSPC`. Error is because of no temp space. I tried using BleachBit and then restart my machine and run the same command then it works well for a while and exit triggering the error again.

BleachBit takes much time to clean and then I have to restart my machine to start it again. Does anyone have any solution for this problem. Because I have checked my system monitor and found 1.8GB RAM is still free to use and its giving error for no space.

Here is the screenshot of my terminal attached below:

Screenshot while running react-native:

[image]

Screenshot with error ENOSPACE:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, could you [edit] the question and add the full error message as text (copy/paste).

Answer (score 0):

**ENOSPC** can arise when you do not have enough space on your hard disk or file partition for your root directory "/" where all installed files are saved.

Open up your "Disk Usage Analyzer" to view how much space you have left and also view directories that are taking up a bunch of space but can be gotten rid of.

When you do this, you should have enough space to start up your project.

Useful commands to use that could get rid of junk and useless files and part files include:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get purge
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

let me know if that helps or you found a better solution